# how to print precise floating double values

Tags: java, android, floating-point

i want to print a double value like `0.000027`,
but it's getting printed as `2.7340E-05`.

i'm using-

```
editTextYARD.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%6.4E"));
```

please help...

Comment: double a;   editTextYARD.setText( String.valueOf(a));

Comment: You specified exponential notation: that's what you got.

Comment: can i print float values based on situations like when i convert 0.01 micrometer to km, it should display 1.0E-11 but in my app its showing "1.0000000000000001E-11"???

Answer (score 1):

This will convert a given double value to show decimal point up to 7

```
double value = 0.0000027;
System.out.println(String.format("%.7f", (double)value));
```

you may use it like this

```
editTextYARD.setText(""+String.format("%.7f", (double)value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `DecimalFormat` for this purpose.

```
 double myvalue = 1.2345678878;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
 df.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
 your_editText.setText(df.format(myvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

When print to console:
  System.out.printf( "%04.2f", var)

When print to string, I think ( I am not tried yet...)
This worth trying..

String ret = String.format ("%04.2f", var)